# Mutable CMake build directory after migrate on AGP 7

Tags: android, c++, android-gradle-plugin

After migrate project on:
Version of Android Gradle Plugin: 7.0.2
Version of Gradle: 7.2

Cmake generate random path for "cxxBuildFolder"
"project_path/.cxx/Debug/503l185r/x86_64"
Path contains "503l185r", this is a dynamic piece.

For build type "release":
"project_path/.cxx/RelWithDebInfo/323p2u6p/x86_64"

if switch to AGP=4.1.1
path is immutable "project_path/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86_64"

This is AGP bug or feature for gradle configuration cache?
How to make path immutable on AGP=7.x.x?

Environment Details
AGP Version: 7.0.2
Gradle Version: 7.2
NDK Version: 23.1.7779620
CMake Version: 3.18.1
Build system: CMake
Host OS: Windows, Linux
ABI: "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"

You can take a test project for experiments in the description of the problem on google issue track:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/214408190

[build with AGP 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lztzB.png)
[build with AGP 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xWjZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be intended change. Please see:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37119426

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32767116)